# Directional derivative of differentiable function on a line segment

Tags: derivatives, differential

Let the function $f: U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on open set $U$. Let $x,y \in U$ be such that the line segment $[x,y] \subset U$. Define the function $g : [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as
$$
g(t):=f(x+t(y-x))
$$
Show that for any $t_* \in [0,1]$, $g'(t_*) = \langle \nabla f(x+t_*(y-x)),y-x\rangle$.

The solution for $t_*=0$ is already here 
[Why is any arbitrary directional derivative always recoverable from the gradient?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2643798/why-is-any-arbitrary-directional-derivative-always-recoverable-from-the-gradient)

However, I do not know how to use that trick and generalize it for all points on the line segment?

Answer (score 1):

Use the notion of [Fréchet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) and the chain rule:

$$\partial g(t)=\partial[f(x+t(y-x))]=\partial f(x+t(y-x))\partial[x+t(y-x)]\\=\partial f(x+t(y-x))(y-x)=\langle\nabla f(x+t(y-x)),y-x\rangle$$

where $\partial$ means "Fréchet derivative of".

Comment: Actually, my first question was not answered which was https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2931023/gateaux-differentiability-of-univariate-function-chain-rule-is-true-for-gateau. In the original question, $f$ was Gateaux differentiable. Could you prove the question posted on the link for me.